# Css adjustment for mobile devices

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

e with the normal css that we use to write will work for the mobile devices too irrespective of the mobile device used. I am working on mobile application where I have written the following css to show some data

```
<div style="float: left; width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 20%; height: auto;">
            <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"
                src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvYw0Fzp3l9dRMBOyRr-MVP_sDgMpyH2V5-iOjHVTzIqlJuwiv3Nsd7fE4" />
        </div>

        <div style="float: left; width: 70%">
            <div style="padding-left: 7%; float: left;">
                <p>Name:</p>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 1%;">
                ABCD
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I am viewing it in simulator with different one the o/p is showing as follows. So can some one help me.

[image]
[image]

Edit as per the answer

```
/*IPad*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1114px) and (max-device-height: 1391px) and (orientation:portrait)
{
    #divName
    {
        margin-left: -6%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1114px) and (max-device-height: 1391px) and (orientation:landscape)
{

    #divName
    {
        margin-left: -11%;
        float: left;
    }
}

/*IPhone*/

@media all and (min-device-width: 440px) and (max-device-height: 802px) and (orientation:landscape)
{

    #divName
    {
        margin-left: 7%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media all and (min-device-width: 440px) and (max-device-height: 802px) and (orientation:portrait)
{

    #divName
    {
        margin-left: 25%;
        float: left;
    }
}

<div style="float: left; width: 70%">
            <div id="divName">
                <p>Name:</p>
            </div>
            <!--<div style="float: left; margin-left: 1%;">
                ABCD
            </div>-->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different styles for each orientation:

```
 @media all and (orientation:portrait) {
 /* Style adjustments for portrait mode goes here */
 }

 @media all and (orientation:landscape) {
   /* Style adjustments for landscape mode goes here */
 }
```

And study more on `media queries`.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: How can I detect that whether the orientation is portarit or landscape or from which device the application is loading

Comment: The `code` I gave you can detect the device orientation. `orientation:portrait` and `orientation:landscape`

Comment: @Ramakrishna You can take a look on this very simple example [If you will resize your window to look like portrait, text color will become green otherwise red]: http://jsfiddle.net/4vp6J/1/

Comment: Thanks one small help, but when I am checking in a simulator and opening it in tab devices how we can adjust the same

Comment: @Ramakrishna I don't really get what you are saying but if you want to adjust your styles depending on screen sizes, then I think you need to  study more on media queries. Such as `min-width`, `max-width`, etc.

Comment: Hi can you check my edits I tried as per your said but when I am changing the devices the css is not applying as per requireed